# Add new Image attribute for category in magento 2.1.1

Tags: magento-2.1.1

I'm trying to create a new attribute as Image for category, I was able to create that attribute, but when I tried to upload an image it was impossible to save.

### This is my code:

**Wage/Categorylist/Setup/InstallData.php**

```
namespace Wage\Categorylist\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Module\Setup\Migration;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetupFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    public function __construct(CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory)
    {
        $this->categorySetupFactory = $categorySetupFactory;
    }
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();

        $categorySetup = $this->categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $entityTypeId = $categorySetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY);
        $attributeSetId = $categorySetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
        $categorySetup->removeAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'thumbnail' );
        $categorySetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'thumbnail', [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Featured Image',
                'input' => 'image',
                'backend' => 'Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Attribute\Backend\Image',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 5,
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'group' => 'General Information',
            ]
        );
        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

**Wage/Categorylist/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="content">
        <field name="thumbnail">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Thumbnail Image</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                    <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/image-preview</item>
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                    <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="categorylist/category_thumbnailimage/upload"/>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**Wage/Categorylist/Controller/Adminhtml/Category/Thumbnailimage/Upload.php**

```
namespace Wage\Categorylist\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Thumbnailimage;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

/**
 * Class Upload
 */
class Upload extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $baseTmpPath;
    protected $imageUploader;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader $imageUploader
    ) {
        $this->imageUploader = $imageUploader;
        parent::__construct($context);

    }
   public function execute() {
        try {
            $result = $this->imageUploader->saveFileToTmpDir('thumbnail');
            $result['cookie'] = [
                'name' => $this->_getSession()->getName(),
                'value' => $this->_getSession()->getSessionId(),
                'lifetime' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieLifetime(),
                'path' => $this->_getSession()->getCookiePath(),
                'domain' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieDomain(),
            ];
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $result = ['error' => $e->getMessage(), 'errorcode' => $e->getCode()];
        }
        return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON)->setData($result);
   }
}
```

**Wage/Categorylist/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Wage\Categorylist\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Thumbnailimage\Upload">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="imageUploader" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\CategoryImageUpload</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\CategoryImageUpload" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="baseTmpPath" xsi:type="string">catalog/tmp/category</argument>
            <argument name="basePath" xsi:type="string">catalog/category</argument>
            <argument name="allowedExtensions" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="jpg" xsi:type="string">jpg</item>
                <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="string">jpeg</item>
                <item name="gif" xsi:type="string">gif</item>
                <item name="png" xsi:type="string">png</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

[image]

I get the following error:

> jquery.js:9666 POST
>   admin/categorylist/category_thumbnailimage/upload/k…9abae110ca00b7329cf2e97fc1b415f4d6dcadd9cdfe7abc8e356bd303bd4/?isAjax=true
>   404 (Forbidden)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You just missing admin router, follow below code for complete solution for category custom image attribute.

Magento custom category image attribute code.

> app/code/Wage/Categorylist/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Wage_Categorylist',
    __DIR__
);
```

> app/code/Wage/Categorylist/composer.json

```
{
    "name": "categorylist/magento2-category-image",
    "description": "Add custom category image attribute",
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0"
    },
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "extra": {
        "map": [
            [
                "*",
                "Wage/Categorylist"
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

> app/code/Wage/Categorylist/etc/module.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Wage_Categorylist" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

> app/code/Wage/Categorylist/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Wage\Categorylist\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Thumbnailimage\Upload">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="imageUploader" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\CategoryImageUpload</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\CategoryImageUpload" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="baseTmpPath" xsi:type="string">catalog/tmp/category</argument>
            <argument name="basePath" xsi:type="string">catalog/category</argument>
            <argument name="allowedExtensions" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="jpg" xsi:type="string">jpg</item>
                <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="string">jpeg</item>
                <item name="gif" xsi:type="string">gif</item>
                <item name="png" xsi:type="string">png</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

> app/code/Wage/Categorylist/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="categorylist" frontName="categorylist">
            <module name="Wage_Categorylist" before="Magento_Backend" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

> app/code/Wage/Categorylist/Setup/InstallData.php

```
<?php
namespace Wage\Categorylist\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Module\Setup\Migration;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetupFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    public function __construct(CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory)
    {
        $this->categorySetupFactory = $categorySetupFactory;
    }
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();

        $categorySetup = $this->categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $entityTypeId = $categorySetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY);
        $attributeSetId = $categorySetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
        $categorySetup->removeAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'thumbnail' );
        $categorySetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'thumbnail', [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Featured Image',
                'input' => 'image',
                'backend' => 'Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Attribute\Backend\Image',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 5,
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'group' => 'General Information',
            ]
        );
        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

> app/code/Wage/Categorylist/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="content">
        <field name="thumbnail">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Thumbnail Image</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                    <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/image-preview</item>
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                    <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="categorylist/category_thumbnailimage/upload"/>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

> app/code/Wage/Categorylist/Controller/Adminhtml/Category/Thumbnailimage/Upload.php

```
<?php
namespace Wage\Categorylist\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Thumbnailimage;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

/**
 * Class Upload
 */
class Upload extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $baseTmpPath;
    protected $imageUploader;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader $imageUploader
    ) {
        $this->imageUploader = $imageUploader;
        parent::__construct($context);

    }
    public function execute() {

        try {
            $result = $this->imageUploader->saveFileToTmpDir('thumbnail');
            $result['cookie'] = [
                'name' => $this->_getSession()->getName(),
                'value' => $this->_getSession()->getSessionId(),
                'lifetime' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieLifetime(),
                'path' => $this->_getSession()->getCookiePath(),
                'domain' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieDomain(),
            ];
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $result = ['error' => $e->getMessage(), 'errorcode' => $e->getCode()];
        }
        return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON)->setData($result);
    }
}
```

**Note :** When you applied abvoe complete code, upload category image show just preview image but after save category, image will not show.

this is magento version default bug.

To solve this issue by apply bellow patch.

Opne this url : `https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/5978/files`

You have to override below core files code with file code from given URL.

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Category/Image/Upload.php
vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Category/Save.php
vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Category.php
vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Category/Attribute/Backend/Image.php
vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Category/DataProvider.php
```

Now magento-2.1 working code for custom image attribute of category.

Let me know if you have any query/consern from above.

Comment: I override but still image is not showing after save category

Comment: You have missed something, verify once again. because of above suggested code working and verify from my side.

Comment: I override all core files through di.xml and I followed the same steps you given. can you please mail your module to jellamahendra@gmail.com. Thnak you!.

Comment: For testing purpose, you can put suggested core file code in core module file without override. try and let me know if you still facing same problem.

Comment: Okay. I will check now.

Comment: @S H Patel. I have created image attribute through your above steps without override any core files, Because i am using version 2.1.2, This version also image not show after saving category. Can you tell me what was the issue.

Comment: @SHParel I've created a module as per your instructions without overriding the core files on magento 2.1.4. But when I upload the image it shows me alert message "The file was not uploaded.". Please see this http://prntscr.com/em3lp4. Any suggestion?

Comment: Above code is tested by me, it's working for me. I guess it is problem with magento version. I will check it with 2.1.4 in my free time if any changes found then I will update my code.

Comment: @SHPatel Thanks! For now, I've made changes in core file as suggested here https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/5978/files. But I'm getting error at frontend and var/report showing this error http://prntscr.com/em3um4. Any idea why this error?

Comment: Fixed that issue by compile command. Your module is working perfectly on 2.1.4 after overriding the core files. (y)

Comment: @SHPatel Code was working fine but after updating 2.1.7 its not working any more. any help ?

Comment: You need to compare core file changes.

Comment: If its not showing up after saving, its because you need to remove the entry for that module in the setup_module table and then run magento setup:upgrade again.

Answer (score 0):

I have created an extension have that feature.

https://github.com/davidduong90/addimages

Hope it helps someone!