# Images uploading, going to the /media/tmp, but not saving in media/catalog after saving category magento 2

Tags: magento2, image-upload

I have created custom image attribute. This is displaying perfect. But when i save category, it is not saving.
Images are uploading perfectly, Saving at /media/tmp, but not saving in media/catalog after saving category magento 2.

Comment: When you upload image, it showing preview before save ?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I just ran into this problem with a custom module.

Answer (score 1):

Magento2.1 Category image upload showing preview after upload image but not working after save category.

this is magento version default bug.

To solve this issue by apply bellow patch.

Opne this url : `https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/5978/files`

You have to override below core files code with file code from given URL.

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Category/Image/Upload.php
vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Category/Save.php
vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Category.php
vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Category/Attribute/Backend/Image.php
vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Category/DataProvider.php
```

Now magento-2.1 working code for custom image attribute of category.

See complete answer for the issue : [See my complete answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138928/add-new-image-attribute-for-category-in-magento-2-1-1/139648#139648)

Let me know if you have any query/concern from above.

Comment: This is still not working

Comment: You can get reference from given my answer otherwise you have add your code so i can debug on that.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by setting the `backend_model` for my attribute in the `eav_attribute` table to `Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Attribute\Backend\Image`

When a category is saved in Magento 2 it walks through the attributes calling the `afterSave` function of each attribute.

As you can see below the function `Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Attribute\Backend\Image::afterSave` moves the file from the tmp folder to correct folder.

```
public function afterSave($object)
{
    $image = $object->getData($this->getAttribute()->getName(), null);

    if ($image !== null) {
        try {
            $this->getImageUploader()->moveFileFromTmp($image);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->_logger->critical($e);
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: this fails in \Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader::moveFileFromTmp as the $baseTmpImagePath contains both $basePath and $baseTmpPath => the copyFile method fails

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have created a preference for Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider, and your new DataProvider has this code in it.

```
class DataProvider extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider {

protected function getFieldsMap()
{
    $fields = parent::getFieldsMap();
    $fields['content'][] = 'custom_attribute_name';
    return $fields;
}
```

Comment: can i override for invoice  abstactpdf.php file ?

Comment: You can override only the public methods of AbstractPdf.php For protected methods, you can override the methods from where these methods are called. For example to override the method called insertLogo, override the Invoice.php which is calling insertLogo in getPdf method.